# Highlight a cell in a column if an input is matched in Google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to create a Google Sheets form where participants can organize themselves into groups of three. Specifically, I want a cell in the "Email List" column (which is fixed and cannot be edited by participants) to be highlighted when a participant enters their email,

[image: similar to the example here]

I very appreciate any help.

I have searched for "Match and Highlight" using Googe Sheet from this website but no answers were helpful to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this result you can use conditional formatting with a custom formula:

```
=MATCH(D2, flatten($A$1:$B$3), 0)
```

- `D2` is the left and top-most cell of the range you need to format.
- `$A$1:$B$3` is the range where you need to search for the values. Important: it has to be fixed (have `$`'s in front of all parts of the coordinates).

Conditional formatting rule:

[image: Conditional formatting rule]

Result:

[image: Result]

[Document with the working example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dR0Zkozr3jZMlnIpVGnJBoBPyzpQyN7c6IqMPVxDc70/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Do you know how to handle the situation when a participant accidentially puts "a blank space" after their email? The match then will not count this.

Comment: @Hanh You can use this updated formula `=MATCH(D2,map(flatten($A$1:$C$10), lambda(s, trim(s))), 0)`.  It removes the whitespace before comparison.